# creating a both side radio wave animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want a Radar wave animation like this:

[image]

With a lot of effort using my poor knowledge of Svgs I added the left side of the desired wave and it works fine. but I need some help to add the right side with a proper solution.

**Note:** if you know any source code or any better solution to achieve such animation which is simpler than mine please fell free to notify me.

**Note 2:** I need a function to initiate the animation.

Thanks in advance.

```js
function Wave() {
  const waves = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave");
  waves.forEach(wave => wave.classList.add('add-wave'));
  
  const wave1 = document.querySelector(".radio-wave-1");
  wave1.classList.add('add-radio-wave-1');
  
  const wave2 = document.querySelector(".radio-wave-2");
  wave2.classList.add('add-radio-wave-2');
  
  const wave3 = document.querySelector(".radio-wave-3");
  wave3.classList.add('add-radio-wave-3');
  
  const wave4 = document.querySelector(".radio-wave-4");
  wave4.classList.add('add-radio-wave-4');
  
  const wave5 = document.querySelector(".radio-wave-5");
  wave5.classList.add('add-radio-wave-5');
  
  const wave6 = document.querySelector(".radio-wave-6");
  wave6.classList.add('add-radio-wave-6');
  
  
}

setTimeout(() => Wave(), 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.left-wave-container {
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.radio-wave-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5rem;
}

.radio-wave-container.content {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.radio-source {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  fill: #fcba03;
}

.add-wave {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.2s;
          animation-duration: 2.2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.radio-wave {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke: #fcba03;
  fill: none;
  transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.add-radio-wave-1 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-1;
          animation-name: wave-1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-2;
          animation-name: wave-2;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
          animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-3 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-3;
          animation-name: wave-3;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
          animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-4 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-4;
          animation-name: wave-4;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
          animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-4 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-4 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-5 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-5;
          animation-name: wave-5;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
          animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-5 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-5 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-6 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-6;
          animation-name: wave-6;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
          animation-delay: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-6 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-6 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="left-wave-container" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <svg style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;" width="0" height="0" version="1.1">
      <defs>
        <symbol id="radio-wave" viewBox="0 0 100 200">
    
          <g>
            <path d="M62.5,185 Q12.5,100 62.5,15" />
          </g>
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="radio-source" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      
        </symbol>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    <div class="radio-wave-container">
      <div class="radio-wave-container content">
        <svg class="radio-source">
          <use xlink:href="#radio-source"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-1">
          <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-2">
          <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-3">
          <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-4">
          <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-5">
          <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-6">
          <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried and what isn't working? And did you write this code you're starting from? Because there's a lot going on in this code, and while writing it you would already have lots of clues as to how to achieve this on the right side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing elements **wave1..wave6** should be like `querySelectorAll`:

```
const wave1 = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave-1");
...
const wave6 = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave-6");
```

Because this is a collection.

Next, I applied a `for` loop, specifying **2** as index to add a class for each **wave1..wave6**.

Also, I decided to correct your html and css layout. If you want your waves to be in the picture that you showed, then you need to do the following:

Use **flex** to align with each other. Add this to your css:

```
.wave-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

And remove rule `margin-right: 50%` from `.left-wave-container` and `.right-wave-container` selectors.

Now it's done!

```js
function Wave() {
  const waves = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave");
  const wave1 = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave-1");
  const wave2 = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave-2");
  const wave3 = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave-3");
  const wave4 = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave-4");
  const wave5 = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave-5");
  const wave6 = document.querySelectorAll(".radio-wave-6");

  waves.forEach(function(wave) {
    wave.classList.add('add-wave');

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {    
      wave1[i].classList.add('add-radio-wave-1'); 
      wave2[i].classList.add('add-radio-wave-2');  
      wave3[i].classList.add('add-radio-wave-3'); 
      wave4[i].classList.add('add-radio-wave-4'); 
      wave5[i].classList.add('add-radio-wave-5'); 
      wave6[i].classList.add('add-radio-wave-6');  
    }  
  });
}

setTimeout(() => Wave(), 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.wave-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.left-wave-container {
  position: relative;
  /*margin-right: 50%;*/
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.right-wave-container {
  position: relative;
  /*margin-right: 50%;*/
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  transform: rotate(180deg); /* flip the animation*/
}

.radio-wave-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 5rem;
}

.radio-wave-container.content {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.radio-source {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  fill: #fcba03;
}

.add-wave {
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2.2s;
          animation-duration: 2.2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
          animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
          animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.radio-wave {
  position: absolute;
  right: 2rem;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke: #fcba03;
  fill: none;
  transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
  opacity: 0;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
}

.add-radio-wave-1 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-1;
          animation-name: wave-1;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
          animation-delay: 0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-1 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-2;
          animation-name: wave-2;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.2s;
          animation-delay: 0.2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-2 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-3 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-3;
          animation-name: wave-3;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
          animation-delay: 0.4s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-3 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-4 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-4;
          animation-name: wave-4;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
          animation-delay: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-4 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-4 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-5 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-5;
          animation-name: wave-5;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.8s;
          animation-delay: 0.8s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-5 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-5 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
.add-radio-wave-6 {
  -webkit-animation-name: wave-6;
          animation-name: wave-6;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
          animation-delay: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes wave-6 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}

@keyframes wave-6 {
  0% {
    transform: scale(0.2) translateX(150%);
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  10% {
    transform: scale(0.3) translateX(50%);
    opacity: 0.3;
  }
  20% {
    transform: scale(0.4) translateX(-40%);
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  30% {
    transform: scale(0.5) translateX(-120%);
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  40% {
    transform: scale(0.6) translateX(-190%);
    opacity: 0.6;
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(0.7) translateX(-250%);
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
  60% {
    transform: scale(0.8) translateX(-300%);
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  70% {
    transform: scale(0.9) translateX(-350%);
    opacity: 0.9;
  }
  80% {
    transform: scale(1) translateX(-400%);
  }
  90% {
    transform: scale(1.1) translateX(-450%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1.2) translateX(-500%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
</head>

<body> 

    <div class="wave-container">

        <div class="left-wave-container" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <svg style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;" width="0" height="0" version="1.1">
              <defs>
                <symbol id="radio-wave" viewBox="0 0 100 200">
                  <g>
                    <path d="M62.5,185 Q12.5,100 62.5,15" />
                  </g>
                </symbol>
                <symbol id="radio-source" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                </symbol>
              </defs>
            </svg>
            <div class="radio-wave-container">
              <div class="radio-wave-container content">
                <svg class="radio-source">
                  <use xlink:href="#radio-source"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-1">
                  <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-2">
                  <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-3">
                  <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-4">
                  <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-5">
                  <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                </svg>
                <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-6">
                  <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                </svg>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



          <div class="right-wave-container" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <svg style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;" width="0" height="0" version="1.1">
                <defs>
                  <symbol id="radio-wave" viewBox="0 0 100 200">
              
                    <g>
                      <path d="M62.5,185 Q12.5,100 62.5,15" />
                    </g>
                  </symbol>
                  <symbol id="radio-source" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                
                  </symbol>
                </defs>
              </svg>
              <div class="radio-wave-container">
                <div class="radio-wave-container content">
                  <svg class="radio-source">
                    <use xlink:href="#radio-source"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-1">
                    <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-2">
                    <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-3">
                    <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-4">
                    <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-5">
                    <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                  </svg>
                  <svg class="radio-wave radio-wave-6">
                    <use xlink:href="#radio-wave"></use>
                  </svg>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

        </div>



    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
transform: rotate(180deg);
```

On a wrapping div will reflect the animation, so you can use it on the right side.

Example:

```
<div class="radio-wave-container">
      <div class="radio-wave-container content">
        <div class="reflect">
            <svg class="radio-source">
            <use xlink:href="#radio-source"></use>
            </svg>
        </div>
...(etc)
```

With the following added to the stylesheet:

```
.reflect {
     transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at new version of the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65584522/right-side-wave-is-not-visible